# Is it possible to develop a virtual world that is accessible via both a PC and a virtual reality headset?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, webvr

For example, if you have a virtual reality headset, you can interact with this virtual world in VR (i.e. WebVR); however, if you don't have a VR headset and/or WebVR compatibility can still access and explore this virtual world (i.e. like Runescape) and interact with characters, whether they are VR or web in the same virtual world?

Comment: This isn't a good question for stack overflow, as it's not programming related, but, yes. Of course, it will have to be designed to be playable for both VR and non VR. An example of a game that integrates both VR and Desktop players is VRChat.

Comment: 2+ client applications, 1 shared  set of servers for online shared world.  This is too broad for  a SO question though, please read [ask]

Comment: Do you have any advice on where to get started (i.e. libraries / tools I could study) and/or would you be interested in collaborating on a new project if you have experience?

Comment: Please read [tour] and  [ask].  This is something for a discussion forum at another site.

Answer (score 0):

The [A-Frame framework](https://aframe.io/) handles that for you automatically, or you can roll it yourself, if you're using another framework.  Either way, the different control schemes require a fair amount of thought.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at React360 (https://facebook.github.io/react-360/), it is a WebVR based framework from Facebook and can handle most 3D media out of the box. It performs quite well and has the advantage of progressive enhancement, i.e. if you view it from a desktop/tablet you get a 2D experience, if you are on a 3D capable device you get a full VR experience.

It's also cross platform so will run on android/iOS/Windows/MacOS/Oculus/Vive. Samples are included with it which should be enough to give you an idea of its capabilities.

Depending on the complexity of the game you are trying to develop and the graphical control required A-Frame is another option to look at.